# Usage of "What" + verb without auxiliary one

Tags: grammar, writing-style

This is a subquestion to my ["And lead raptivity captive"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/and-lead-raptivity-captive) question.

As I understood from a comment by RegDwight, it was incorrect to ask:

- What mean raptivity and phrase "And lead raptivity captive"?

Do I miss something or I incorrectly memorized the lessons of:

- [Who + Auxiliary](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/134358-who-auxiliary.html#post676765)
- I can find other links
  ?

Update: 
<strike>The anwers do not address my question</strike>
Are the answers in given above link correct or not?

Comment: Don't read Finnegan's Wake if you're still learning English! For practical purposes, that book is not written in English at all.

Comment: I stopped learning English 20 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem: you are missing the fact that it makes a difference whether the [WH-word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word) is the subject or the object in the sentence.

Let's start with a sentence with no questions:

> John saw Mary yesterday.

In this sentence, *John* is the subject and *Mary* is the object.

Now, if someone doesn't know about John, they might ask:

> 1) *Who* saw Mary yesterday?

This sentence has the structure that you are using, where the main verb comes after *who*.  But this is true only when *who* is the subject.  When it is the object, things are different — now let's imagine that the asker doesn't know about Mary:

> 2) *Who* did John see yesterday?

In this sentence, because *who* is the object, the word order is different. Instead of having the main verb after *who*, we have [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support), with *do* in the past tense, and the main verb following *John* with infinitive form.

So, in your example, the information is:

> [*Raptivity* and the phrase "and lead raptivity captive"] means ***_*__*_*__**.

The blank line is the information you don't know.  As you can see, it is in the object position.  That means you must structure your sentence like (2), instead of (1):

> What do *raptivity* and the phrase "and lead raptivity captive" mean?

Answer (score 2):

You should say:

> What does 'raptivity', and the phrase 'And lead raptivity captive', mean?

You perhaps need to work on your tenses as:

> Do I miss something or I incorrectly memorized the lessons

is also a little off. It should be:

> *Did* I miss something or *did* I incorrectly *memorize* the lessons

As you asking whether you missed something in the past, you have to use the past tense of *do*, which is *did*.

Answer (score 1):

> Update: The anwers do not address my question. Are the answers in given above link correct or not?

The link says

> “Who” is the subject ... so you don´t need an auxiliary.

So far as I know, the answer is correct - but it doesn't describe the situation as fully or precisely as the answers here.

Comment: Can I skip auxiliary verb in what-question also?

Comment: If "what" represents the subject: "What hit me?" Not if "what" represents the object: "What did I hit?"

Answer (score 0):

The format of a question is *modal verb* *subject* *verb* *object*.

> Do you like ice creams?
>   Do you need help?
>   May I help you?
>   Would you like it?

When the verb is a tense of *to be* the question format is *verb* _subject_ *modifier*.

> Are you sure?
>   Is she happy?
>   Is she your wife?

When using interrogative pronouns, they are added at the beginning of the question.

> What do you like better?
>   Who is Mary?
>   How are you?
>   Where do you live?
>   When should I go to visit her?

Comment: This is strange that you completely ignored your own [Who turned off the lights?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/who-turned-off-the-lights), isn't this?

Comment: I didn't forget my question. My question was about questions with _who_; this question is about questions with _what_.