# Word order in subject sentences (questions)

Tags: grammar, word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of “What” + verb without auxiliary one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10665/usage-of-what-verb-without-auxiliary-one)

I have probably not used the correct term but I am sure you will get it.

If a question has do-support, then in the answer the word order changes back to indicative:

> Q: Where does he live?
>   A: I do not know **where he lives**.

But if there is no do-support in the question, does the word order remain the same in the answer?

> Q: What is wrong with him?
>   A: I do not know **what is wrong** with him.

Is it like that?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is a duplicate. In any case, yes, it is like that, and the reason is that in the first question, the subject is *he*, so you need do-support. In the second example, the subject is the question word itself, *what*, so no do-support is necessary. So you are kind of approaching this from the wrong angle. It's not that the word order "remains the same *in the answer*" to the second question; much rather, it doesn't change *in the question* in the first place.

Comment: Found a question that explains this in further detail. Read [the top answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/10672/300) there, by an actual linguist.